# Путаница с неполными предложениями

Tags: синтаксис

Много непонятного для себя открыл.
Цитирую справочник:

```
Мы вышли из лесу и попытались сориентироваться на местности. Потом пошли по тропинке вправо
```

Автор считает, что здесь двусоставное неполное. Поскольку из контекста ясно, что речь о "мы", которое во втором случае опускается. Логично.
Хорошо, а если бы не было предыдущего предложения, то же самое было бы здесь?

```
Потом пошли по тропинке справа.
```

Ведь это прошедшее время. Лица здесь быть не может. Почему не считать его неопределенно-личным и полным? Как вообще тогда по этим примерам можно понять, что какое-то полное, а что нет?

К тому же у автора есть совершенно непонятная для меня фраза: "Предложения или части сложного предложения без подлежащего со сказуемым в прошедшем времени или в условном наклонении должны быть охарактеризованы как двусоставные неполные..."
По этой логике вообще не может быть неопределенно-личных полных предложений, очень все запутано теперь для меня. Подскажите.

Answer (score 1):

***Потом пошли по тропинке.***

Это двусоставное неполное предложение.  Его нельзя считать  неопределенно-личным (**по семантике**).

**Пояснение**

1. Производитель действия в **неполных** предложениях восстанавливается **из контекста** (необязательно из предыдущего предложения) и поэтому всегда ясен.
2. Неопределенно-личные предложения имеют собственную **грамматическую форму и семантику** согласно определению:

В неопределённо-личных предложениях главный член выражается **глаголом в форме 3 лица** **множественного числа** (настоящего и будущего времени в изъявительном наклонении и в повелительном наклонении), формой **множественного числа** **прошедшего времени** изъявительного наклонения и аналогичной формой условного наклонения глагола. Производитель действия в этих предложениях **неизвестен или неважен:** *В дверь **стучат/постучали**. Пусть стучат. Если бы стучали громче, я бы услышал.*

[Е. И. Литневская Русский язык: краткий теоретический курс для школьников](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm)

3. Соответственно, мы не можем считать "Потом пошли по тропинке" неопределенно-личным предложением. Хотя форма прошедшего времени **возможна**, но **семантика** здесь не та. В этом случае производитель действия  **известен** из контекста.

**Сравнить**: *Стучать перестали. **Ушли**.* Это **неопределенно-личное** предложение, производитель действия неизвестен или неважен.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139540/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon----).